# Unable to get rid of page margins, header and footers at print in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page, it contains a 'Printable View' button, upon clicking this all the content of the will be auto-populated to 'Bootstrap' modal.

This modal contains a 'Print' button, upon clicking this, the modal will be printed not the page.

Below is the CSS,

```
@media print{
    body.modal-open {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    body.modal-open .modal .modal-header,
    body.modal-open .modal .modal-body {
        visibility: visible; /* make visible modal body and header */
    }

    body.modal-open .modal {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: visible!important;
    }
}
```

JS,

```
$('#modal-Printbtn').click(function(){
        window.print();
});
```

As it is long scrollable modal, i have added 'Overflow:visible'. Now the issues are,

**1. Margins and Headers,Footers :**

a) In Chrome,

I tried

```
@media Print{ 
    @page {margin:0; }
}
```

this removed headers and footers and margins too. This is good.

b) In IE,

The above CSS is not at all getting reflected, margins exist along with headers and footers.

**2. Extra Pages :**

Both in IE & Chrome,

Even if the content fits in 6 pages of print, 2 extra pages always add at the end. I tried all kinds of page-break properties, none of them works.

At this point, i don't want to experiment with plugins.

Both are critical issues to users. Can someone please help me, this is frustrating.

Thanks,

Comment: Making an element `visiblity: hidden` does not stop it from taking up room in the layout.

Comment: @Pointy I didn't understand your point, could you please elaborate more.

Comment: If you make an element `visibility: hidden;` then it will not be shown, but (for example) if it's a 500-pixel tall `<div>` it will still use up 500 pixels. It's basically the same thing as `opacity: 0;`. That may be what's giving you two extra pages at the end of your printouts.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for explanation. Could you suggest me a way to get rid of extra pages. I have tried display : none; , but it hides the complete modal.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i was able to resolve 'Issue - 1 : Page Margins',

I have separated my CSS code like this, @media screen{} & @media print{}. I added CSS in @media Screen{} but missed in @media print{}, later after adding this in both sections resolved my issue - 1.

```
@media screen{  
     @page{
        margin:0;
    }

    #stp-printViewVisitModal .modal-dialog {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #stp-printViewVisitModal .modal-content {     
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 0;
      overflow:auto;
    }   
    #stp-printViewVisitModal *{
        font-size:x-small !important;
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out, why IE pointed this issue but not chrome.